# VS Code Flutter Widget Tree Export

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, widget

#### Is it possible to *export* the full contents of the Widget Inspector as text ?

(ideally with all of the property values of each widget included also)

I'm trying to debug something and I want to compare the full state of my app in one situation, to the full state of my app in another situation.  I'm using VS Code and programming in Flutter.

[image: This is what I want to export]

**Alternatively**, is there another `dart` way that I could export the full state of my application somehow, in such a way that I could grab a 2nd snapshot in a different state of my application and compare the 2 of them as plain text?

Comment: *"Is it possible to export the full contents of the Widget Inspector as text ?"* - check `Widget.toStringDeep` method

Comment: alternatively you can use `Widget.toDiagnosticsNode` if you want a raw `DiagnosticsNode` and export it as a json or other custom format